# Android - Saving data to an accessable location

Tags: java, android, save

I've searched and searched on how to make android output information to a location that can be accessed easily and found nothing (that I can understand anyway)

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
             // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.

             if (location != null) {
                 double lat = location.getLatitude();
                 double lng = location.getLongitude();

                 location_text = "latitude: "+lat+"longitude: "+lng;
                 String FILENAME = "GPS_Log.csv";
                 String entry = "lat" + "," + "lng" + "\n"; // Log all data here!

                 try {
                     FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
                     out.write( entry.getBytes() );
                     out.close();
                 } catch(Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
```

I dont want to root the phone in order to access data/data. I have verified that it is indeed saving the information to the .csv file on a virtual device within studio manager, but I really need easy access to it on a non-rooted phone.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Solved it finally! Issue is with windows and its connection. Using    File(root.getAbsolutePath()+"/Download/MyAppFile"); it puts the folder and file in the correct spot. Windows doesnt see the newly created folders/files until you restart the phone.